# How to stop systemd-journal utilizing 100% cpu resource Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Focal Fossa) and creating Automatically 360 MB of journal files per minute

Tags: 20.04, process

In my Ubuntu 20 Desktop system Every Minute 360 MB of journal log data is generated and my processor is busy with 100% utilization running `systemd-journal`.

Every minute it is storing 128Mb * 3 files in `/var/log/journal/42b76941196c44ebabf29f6efc5047c7/` Folder

I am clearing log with this command manually.

```
sudo journalctl --vacuum-size=50M
Deleted archived journal /var/log/journal/42b76941196c44ebabf29f6efc5047c7/system@00000000000000000000000000000000-00000000015de62d-0005a8bd92211c3a.journal (128.0M).
Deleted archived journal /var/log/journal/42b76941196c44ebabf29f6efc5047c7/system@00000000000000000000000000000000-000000000160c6b7-0005a8bd93351c1b.journal (128.0M).
Deleted archived journal /var/log/journal/42b76941196c44ebabf29f6efc5047c7/system@00000000000000000000000000000000-000000000163a7b1-0005a8bd945c0bf2.journal (128.0M).
Vacuuming done, freed 3.8G of archived journals from /var/log/journal/42b76941196c44ebabf29f6efc5047c7.
Vacuuming done, freed 0B of archived journals from /run/log/journal.
```

3.8 GB of data created in just few minutes and the journal files keeps on getting created and my cpu is busy always 100%

Currently I have done this setting changed:

Using `sudo nano /etc/systemd/journald.conf`, I modified this settings

```
SystemMaxUse=50M
Software=none           -- After adding this line it stopped creating files but systemd-journal process is eating 100% of cup
MaxLevelStore=err
MaxLevelSyslog=warning
MaxLevelKMsg=warning
MaxLevelConsole=err
```

```
> top
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                             >
328 root      19  -1  468040 265696 263872 R 100.0   1.6  31:13.14 systemd-journal
```

```
/var/log/journal/42b76941196c44ebabf29f6efc5047c7  ls -lhsa
total 3.5G
 12K drwxr-sr-x+ 2 root systemd-journal  12K Jun 23 11:01 .
4.0K drwxr-sr-x+ 3 root systemd-journal 4.0K Jun 15 02:45 ..
129M -rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 128M Jun 23 10:53 system@00000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000b928b7-0005a8bd50cff991.journal
129M -rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 128M Jun 23 10:53 system@00000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000bc0a5c-0005a8bd51dfebc1.journal
129M -rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 128M Jun 23 10:53 system@00000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000beeae8-0005a8bd5327bbb9.journal
129M -rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 128M Jun 23 10:54 system@00000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000c1cf12-0005a8bd5491ec30.journal
129M -rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 128M Jun 23 10:54 system@00000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000c4b0ab-0005a8bd55a40899.journal
129M -rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 128M Jun 23 10:54 system@00000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000c7947b-0005a8bd56bf31e1.journal
129M -rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 128M Jun 23 10:54 system@00000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000ca7b31-0005a8bd57e08298.journal
129M -rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 128M Jun 23 10:55 system@00000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000cd5d82-0005a8bd58f27c6f.journal
129M -rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 128M Jun 23 10:55 system@00000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000d0421e-0005a8bd5a0eb633.journal
129M -rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 128M Jun 23 10:55 system@00000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000d324e0-0005a8bd5b414cea.journal
129M -rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 128M Jun 23 10:56 system@00000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000d60651-0005a8bd5c5b194e.journal
129M -rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 128M Jun 23 10:56 system@00000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000d8eb81-0005a8bd5d7f5e1d.journal
129M -rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 128M Jun 23 10:56 system@00000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000dbd098-0005a8bd5e9a9369.journal
129M -rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 128M Jun 23 10:57 system@00000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000deb64b-0005a8bd5fbe668e.journal
129M -rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 128M Jun 23 10:57 system@00000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000e19c03-0005a8bd60d8c9fe.journal
129M -rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 128M Jun 23 10:57 system@00000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000e4814d-0005a8bd61ee85f3.journal
129M -rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 128M Jun 23 10:58 system@00000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000e766ad-0005a8bd63092fa2.journal
129M -rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 128M Jun 23 10:58 system@00000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000ea47e6-0005a8bd6420b7d5.journal
129M -rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 128M Jun 23 10:58 system@00000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000ed2b78-0005a8bd6592ecbf.journal
129M -rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 128M Jun 23 10:59 system@00000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000f011ae-0005a8bd66fd52a8.journal
129M -rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 128M Jun 23 10:59 system@00000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000f2f60c-0005a8bd68164432.journal
129M -rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 128M Jun 23 10:59 system@00000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000f5d72f-0005a8bd69297455.journal
129M -rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 128M Jun 23 11:00 system@00000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000f8bb3a-0005a8bd6a453704.journal
129M -rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 128M Jun 23 11:00 system@00000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000fb9c70-0005a8bd6b770daa.journal
129M -rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 128M Jun 23 11:00 system@00000000000000000000000000000000-0000000000fe8190-0005a8bd6c92d47f.journal
129M -rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 128M Jun 23 11:01 system@00000000000000000000000000000000-00000000010166e5-0005a8bd6dac401f.journal
129M -rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 128M Jun 23 11:01 system@00000000000000000000000000000000-0000000001044c9e-0005a8bd6ecfe4c3.journal
 24M -rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal  24M Jun 23 11:01 system.journal
8.0M -rw-r-----+ 1 root systemd-journal 8.0M Jun 23 11:01 user-1000.journal
```

System Details :

```
$ cat /etc/os-release

NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

How can I stop systemd-journal so that it does not utilize 100% of cpu resources?

Comment: Please format your post properly. Please read [How to format posts](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting), [Markdown editing help](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) and [How to format code properly](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14089/please-can-people-format-code-properly).

Comment: This is not normal, but the logs are filled for a reason. Opening any of these logs with an editor should make the problem rather obvious, and fixing the problem should quiesce the logging...

Answer (score 0):

Here are few steps which I performed after looking at the logs.

In my /var/log folder these two files were also taking up 71 GB of space each.

```
cd /var/log

ls -lsha

71G -rw-r-----   1 syslog            adm              71G Jun 24 15:51 kern.log
71G -rw-r-----   1 syslog            adm              71G Jun 24 15:52 syslog
```

Did tailing on this files

```
sudo tail -n 10 /var/log/syslog

Jun 24 15:52:17 crusader update-notifier.desktop[3393]: Cannot stat file /proc/3137/fd/10: Permission denied
Jun 24 15:52:17 crusader update-notifier.desktop[3393]: Cannot stat file /proc/3137/fd/11: Permission denied
Jun 24 15:52:17 crusader update-notifier.desktop[3393]: Cannot stat file /proc/3137/fd/16: Permission denied
Jun 24 15:52:17 crusader update-notifier.desktop[3393]: Cannot stat file /proc/3137/fd/17: Permission denied
Jun 24 15:52:48 crusader gnome-shell[1903]: Some code accessed the property 'discreteGpuAvailable' on the module 'appDisplay'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
Jun 24 15:52:48 crusader gnome-shell[1903]: ../clutter/clutter/clutter-actor.c:10556: The clutter_actor_set_allocation() function can only be called from within the implementation of the ClutterActor::allocate() virtual function.
```

```
sudo tail -n 10 /var/log/kern.log

ieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID) Jun 2 pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000 kernel: [ 178.057760] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: [ 0] RxErr
```

I opened the grub file and modified this line..

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub

#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='quiet splash'

with this below line

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='quiet splash pci=noaer'
```

ctrl o
enter
ctrl x
reboot

Rebooted my system and when I run top command now my cpu utilization is back to earlier. ie, systemd-journal process is not running and not utilizing 100% of my cpu usage.

as of now system is running fine.

I also ran few commands before running thie above commands.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Please clarify what is `pci=noaer`.

Comment: Hi Vitaly Zdanevich,

pci=noaer

       ->> AER (Advanced Error Reporting )
       ->> When we set pci=noaer It ask the kernel to not use/log. ie, Advance     
           Error Reporting. 

1) Open Grub file

    sudo nano /etc/default/grub

2) update with this below line

   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='quiet splash pci=noaer'

3) Next clear the log

   sudo dd if=/dev/null of=/var/log/syslog

4) and then check 
   
   sudo dd if=/dev/null of=/var/log/kern.log

Comment: Your hardware is failing, and you have just silenced the alarm about it. 0:1c.5 is likely part of some mainboard component, if one of those is showing PCIe errors that is a massive problem.